# Apple Mach-O Linker Error, Failed to exit with code 1

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I downloaded a library from https://github.com/objective-see/ProcInfo and included it in my Xcode Project as per instructions.

[image: I have included a screenshot]

I tried :

- cleaning the build
- deleting derived data
- Setting bitcode value to no

Am i missing something?
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.
The name of a class and the name of a class in my program were the same.
I changed that and the program compiled.
Thanks.